# How can I create a a playlist file of all of the mp3s in the current directory from the terminal?

Tags: software-recommendation, command-line, mp3

I'm looking for a solution to this or a recommendation for a program to check out. I'd appreciate any help.

**Update**

I would like to use the playlist file with [PowerAMP](http://powerampapp.com/) for android.

Comment: Is there a specific mp3 program/device you are intending to use these playlists for?

Comment: I updated the question. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If an m3u file will suffice, just create a text file containing the directory you want (e.g. `/home/user/music_for_playlist/` and save it with an m3u extension. m3u playlists allow this as a special instance, you don't have to enumerate all the files in the directory (your player does that when you open the playlist).

Alternatively, the following will create an m3u playlist containing all the mp3/wav/ogg/wma files in the current directory, this may be better if you want to exclude specific files or re-save the playlist:

```
find . -iregex '.*\.\(mp3\|wav\|ogg\|wma\)' -print > playlist.m3u
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following command (while in the directory with the needed mp3s):

```
find `pwd` | grep .mp3 > playlist.m3u
```

You can then pass this to a program that accepts playlists via the command line.

Comment: what is pwd here..

Comment: @karthick87 It is the command pwd. It is print working directory. When you put it inside back quotes with find, it'll give you absolute paths, rather than relative to the current directory.

Comment: Having abosulte paths reduces the portability of the playlist